# Rails, ActiveRecord, how to find foreign rows that are NOT there?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

The title is a bit difficult to put together for this question.

Say I have two models, Foo and Bar. Foo has many Bar's. Bar belongs to one Foo. How do I use Foo.find to find all of the Foos that currently have zero Bars? In SQL this would translate into something like:

```
SELECT * from foo where id NOT IN (select foo_id from bar);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Foo.all(:conditions => ["id NOT IN (?)", Bar.all.map(&:foo_id)])` will do it, though there are likely optimizations you can take from there.

If there are speed concerns with this, you might want to look into using a counter cache, which would turn the query into `Foo.find_all_by_bars_count(0)`

Documentation on counter caches is [here](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html#M001318).

Comment: You could use ```Bar.all.ids``` here and avoid pulling all the data in, fwiw.